# how do i fix sudo: unable to resolve host raspberrypi4: Name or service not known

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sudo

i have been running into this problem that makes me unable to use sudo for the past while on my raspberry pi 4 but when i look in the /etc/hosts folder i see this

```
192.168.0.22    localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

192.168.0.22    hostname
```

and the /etc/hostname says `hostname`

by the way my host name is ------------ but i'll replace it with hostname

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sudo command trying to search for hostname](https://superuser.com/questions/429790/sudo-command-trying-to-search-for-hostname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you manually edited your `/etc/hosts` file?

It should look more list this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters
```

Localhost is usually 127.0.0.1 and many services require this to function properly.

Restore it to default and add a line at the bottom `192.168.0.22  <your.hostname>`

For a more detailed explanation of how address resolution works in Linux, start with `man 5 nsswitch.conf`