# Why would sudo complain about DNS name resolution?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, sudo

I'm running on Ubuntu 22 Linux.  When I try to manually fix my `/etc/resolv.conf` file using

```
sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
# or
sudo cp $HOME/tmp/working-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

The command appears to hang before executing the command, the error message produced is

```
sudo: unable to resolve host my-hostname: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

**Why is `sudo` trying to do a DNS name lookup?  And how can I configure it to *not do that*?**

### Background:

If you are wondering why my DNS name queries are failing, they are failing due to an error condition that happens in my companies VPN scripts that leave my Linux host unable to resolve any hostnames via DNS.

I've tracked the problem down to my `/etc/resolv.conf` file is pointing to the companies DNS server which is only accessible when I'm connected via the VPN.
This is generally fine except when my VPN stops working and the company tells me I'm forced to reboot in order to get my system to be usable again.

I don't like the idea of having to reboot because it completely disrupts my workflow during the day.  So, I'm trying to figure out how to properly reset the VPN when it gets "messed up".

### Searching for solutions

Found it!
[sudo command trying to search for hostname](https://superuser.com/questions/429790/sudo-command-trying-to-search-for-hostname)

Comment: "Found it!" – What was the point of posting this question then? It will be closed as a duplicate of the one you have found. Unless… Unless your primary question is "how can I configure `sudo` to not do that?" and the answers to the other question do not solve this. Doesn't `Defaults !fqdn` solve this? I totally don't know. If this is the case then please [edit] and rebuild, concentrate on the actual question (e.g. the title should be different) and clearly state that the alleged duplicate does not solve your problem.

Comment: I closed your question because of your own claim you found a solution elsewhere. If this is wrong then please follow my first comment and rebuild your post. I will reopen it then.

Comment: Closing this as a dup is the right thing.  I considered deleting my question until I read the other question and realized the situation that I ran into with my  DNS `/etc/resolv.conf` file is messed up might be of value to someone else.

Comment: The solution to this is to add the `Defaults !fqdn` string to the *sudoers file* (via `sudo visudo`)